# Vertical scrollbar inside a div without overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am trying to create a simular "tooltip" for my project.

[image]

The problem is that the parent container has the "overflow-y: scroll" property applied to it (I need a vertical scroll bar there) and it simply clips its children elements when I try to move them out of the container. Is there any way I can have a vertical scrollbar without overflow-y?

This is what I have and what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: try `overflow-y:scroll` and `overflow-x:visible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow does indeed eat up any elements you want to hang out of the side. That's what overflow does. For this exact reason, the tooltips tend to not be child elements of the element they relate to, but rather top-level elements positioned absolutely, figured out with JS.

Essentially, you'd do something the likes of this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Todd</a>
        <div class="tooltip-content">Todd is a guy and he's pretty cool.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The basic idea is to have a hidden div that contains your tooltip data, and another div in the top level which you position absolutely.

**JavaScript**

```
    $("ul li a").hover(function(){
        //hover in
        $("#tooltip").html($(this).next().html()).show(); // put the content of .tooltip-content into #tooltip, and show it
        // figure out the position of the element we hovered over
        var tt_top = $(this).offset().top,
            tt_left = $(this).offset().left;
        // position the tooltip based on that data
        // same height, left + width of the ul, so the tooltip is on the right side of the ul
        $("#tooltip").css({
            top: tt_top
            left: tt_left + $("ul").width();
        });
    }, function(){
        // hover out
        $("#tooltip").empty().hide(); // empty and hide tooltip
    });
```

For brevity, I've used jQuery here, but the same principles apply to a pure JavaScript solution as well, if you have the time for that.

**CSS**

```
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        /* tooltip styles */
    }

    .tooltip-content {
        display: none;
    }
```

The tooltip container needs to be positioned absolutely. The `top` and `left` values are created in JavaScript. Add `display:none;` so it doesn't disrupt the rest of your page when unneeded.

Also add `display:none;` to hide the `.tooltip-content` elements so that they are never visible; they're only containers for the HTML you want in the tooltip.

I've not tested this code, but this is the basic principle of all tooltips, when you want to combat `overflow`.

Comment: any suggestions on how I can figure out the absolute positioning of the tooltip relatively to an element I want to attach it to?

Comment: I made a similar solution inspired by this, where I listened to a mouse event, and grabbed the position of the element from the event payload, and then applied it as an absolute position to the element.